# Method of averaging periodic timeseries data

Tags: python, post-processing

I'm in the process of collecting O2 data for work. This data shows periodic behavior. I would like to parse out each repetition to thereby get statistical information like average and theoretical error. [Data Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAp7T.jpg)

Is there a convenient way programmatically:

1. Identify cyclical data?
2. Pick out starting & ending indices such that repeating cycle can be concatenated, post-processed, etc.

I had a few ideas, but am more lacking the Python programing experience.

1. Brute force, condition data in Excel prior. (Will likely collect similar data in future, would like more robust method).
2. Train NN to identify cycle then output indices. (Limited training set, would have to label).
3. Decompose to trend/seasonal data apply Fourier series on seasonal data. Pick out N cycles.
4. Heuristically, i.e. identify thresholds of rate of change & event detection (difficult due to secondary hump, please see data).

Is there a Python program that systematically does this for me? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample Data

Comment: You can use autocorrelation to identify the period of the repeats

Comment: @mozway.  which module does autocorrelation come from ?   i was going to suggest scikit-learn...

Comment: @D.L I was suggesting a general mathematical process, not a specific module. There are many ways (numpy, pandas, matplotlib..). Maybe Ryan could provide the dataset for us to show an example?